# Newton's binomial theorem with induction

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm trying to prove Newton's Binomial Theorem using induction.
I saw a resolution to help me doing it but in every resolution I found there's a point when they write

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}=b^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}$

I don't understand some hidden steps between this 2 expressions... Can someone explain me?

Comment: I edited your formula, but I had to do some guessing because it wasn't clear what you meant. Please check if what I wrote is the formula you had in mind

Comment: Yes it was that formula. How do you write this formulas here? Is there a program?

Comment: see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a good introduction

Comment: If instead of `$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1} = b^{n+1} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}$` you type `$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1} = b^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}$` (without `\limits`) then instead of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}=b^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}$ you will see this: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1}=b^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden step but just a shifting of index in summation notation.

If you imagine breaking up the left hand side into two pieces(k=0 and k=1 to n).

The first piece should be $\begin{pmatrix} n\\0\\  \end{pmatrix}$$a^0$ $b^{n-0+1}$ (this is just by substitute k=0) which equals to $b^{n+1}$, that's the first term of the R.H.S and the remaining part is just the second piece (k=1 to n)

Comment: Oh ok! I understood, I'm going to try again, thanks!